# Aplying numpy.random.normal in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, normal-distribution

I´ve a huge numpy array (68M records) containing mean and std deviation pairs.

I'd like to create a third column estimated using numpy.random.normal using the other columns values.

It is possible? If it isn´t, what´s the best (fast) way to do that?

Comment: `np.random.normal` accepts arrays as arguments.  Just past the first column of your data as the first argument, and the second column as the second argument.

Comment: It worked and it´s astonishing fast, tks.